# Filter Log Files and Select show only unique Values

Tags: logging, filter

I need to look through thousands of log entries in multiple files and find lines with a specific word in them. From the list of lines that contain the one word, I need to filter out lines with unique strings that are part of the line.

For example, see the log files below and lets say I need to find all log lines that contain the word "Test". Then, of all those lines that contain the word "Test" I need to look at the rest of the line and only select one instance of each event. For example if there are two lines that contain "Source 192.168.0.1 Port 23 Destination 192.168.0.2 Port 23", regardless of what the rest of the line is, I want to record only one instance of the line.

Comment: Please don't destroy questions that have good answers. I've rolled back your edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a *nix commandline, there's [grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) (differs slightly between implementations). With GNU/grep, there's the "-m" switch which stops at the first match, e.g.:

```
$ grep Test log.txt | grep -m1 'Source 192.168.0.1 Port 23 Destination 192.168.0.2 Port 23'
-10-30-123-012-031-22 Test Source 192.168.0.1 Port 23 Destination 192.168.0.2 Port 23 djlkdj
```

To search for e.g. "Test" in the logfile and then care for certain parts only, I like to "clean" the logfile with [sed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

```
$ grep Test log.txt | sed 's/.*Test/Test/;s/ djlkdj$//' | sort | uniq -c
   4 Test Source 192.168.0.1 Port 23 Destination 192.168.0.2 Port 23
   2 Test Source 192.168.0.1 Port 23 Destination 192.168.0.222 Port 25
   4 Test Source 192.168.0.1 Port 25 Destination 192.168.0.2 Port 23
   2 Test Source 192.168.5.1 Port 23 Destination 192.168.0.2 Port 23
```

Not sure if this is what you wanted.